# How to define Java's Object[] someObject=new Object[10] in Actionscript

Tags: arrays, actionscript

I have a class named Component and it has a code like this

```
class Component {

var ID:String;
var typical:String;
var connection:String;
var temperature:String;
var voltage:String;

var visibility:Boolean = true;

public function Component(type:String, temperature:String, connection:String,        voltage:String) {


    this.typical = type;
    this.temperature = temperature;
    this.connection = connection;
    this.voltage = voltage;

}

public function setVisibility(b:Boolean):Void {

    visibility = b;

}

}
```

I would like to create an array instance of this class just like in java (like Component[] someComponent = new Component[10]) How can I define this is Actionscript?

Answer (score 0):

In Flash Player 10, Adobe added the [Vector](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html) class. It is the typed array you are looking for. You can make a vector like this:

```
private var vector:Vector.<SomeComponent> = new Vector.<SomeComponent>(10);
private var anotherOne:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>;
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer. I found something that might be another example.
just define an array like

```
var myArray:Array=new Array();
```

after that define each element of the array as another object, like

```
myArray[0]=new Component(); //Here Component is the class which I defined and showed in my original question.
```